# how to convert an csh to zsh alias that requires arguments

Tags: zsh, zshrc

When using [csh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) I use this alias:

```
alias s autossh -M 0 -t \!:1 \"tmux -2 attach -t $USER\!:2 -d \|\| tmux -2 new -s $USER\!:2 \"
```

That can help me to ssh to a remote server by using something like:

```
s 10.11.12.3 X
```

Where X is the suffix `$USERX` of the remote [tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) session the one I can attach or create in case it doesn't exists.

I am currently using [zsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) but would like to continue using the same alias, therefore I would like to know how to properly convert this alias to work under zsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a shell function. `csh` uses aliases only because it doesn't have functions.

```
s () {
    autossh -M 0 -t "$1" "tmux -2 attach -t $USER$2 -d || tmux -2 new -s $USER$2 "
}
```

(I think I replaced the parameters correctly, but it's been a few decades since I used `csh`.)